# Why are page link not working in Cordova Angular?

Tags: angular, cordova

I have an angular application. I convert that application to an android App in Cordova. home page working properly, but angular route links not working. below are my Cordova index.html and route links

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple- 
icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>Now UI Kit Angular by Creative Tim</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, 
user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
<base href="./">
<!--     Fonts and icons     -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="sidebar-collapse">
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script 
type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>



const routes: Routes =[
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'index',                component: ComponentsComponent },
{ path: 'nucleoicons',          component: NucleoiconsComponent },
{ path: 'examples/landing',     component: LandingComponent },
{ path: 'examples/login',       component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'examples/profile',     component: ProfileComponent },
{ path: 'odia',     component: OdiaComponent }
];
```

Comment: please elaborate, how are you trying to navigate? is it using routerLink?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is related to the 'dot' in base href:

```
<base href="./">
```

So if you check it and remove a dot it will work, but there will be a problem with the loading of static files.

I had a similar problem and resolved it in a next way:

1. Remove  `<base href="./">` from your **index.html** file
2. In your main **app.module.ts** file add next provider:

```
<your imports>
...
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [<your imports if are>...],
  exports: [<your exports if are>...],
  providers: [<your providers if are>...,
              {
                provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
                useValue: '/'
              }]
})
```

3. Then rebuild your cordova project. Should work